# XSLT: Merge child elements

Tags: xslt-2.0

Hi I am trying to merge child nodes into a single node containing all the data.

Here is my sample XML,

```
<root>
<list>
<label>Label 1</label>
    <item>some text</item>
<label>Label 2</label>
    <item>some text</item>
    <item>some more text </item>
    <item>some more text</item>
<label>Label 3</label>
    <item>other text</item>
    <item>some text</item>
    <item>some more text</item>
</list>
</root>
```

I need to merge item nodes following label element into one group  and contents into

tag. Desired output is like below

```
<root>
    <list>
    <label>Label 1</label>
        <item>some text</item>
    <label>Label 2</label>
        <item><p>some text</p>
        <p>some more text </p>
        <p>some more text</p></item>
    <label>Label 3</label>
        <item><p>other text</p>
        <p>some text</p>
        <p>some more text</p></item>
    </list>
</root>
```

So far i tried following template but does not work as it should be, it merges all items in to one but i need to tag them into separate p tags. Thanks for help.

```
<xsl:template match="list">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-adjacent="boolean(self::item)">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key()">
                    <item>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()/node()"/>
                    </item>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are close, you only need to make sure process the grouped `item` elements with a template creating `p` elements:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="list">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-adjacent="boolean(self::item)">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key()">
                    <item>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                    </item>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="item">
        <p>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </p>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

That way (http://xsltransform.net/naZXpWX) I get

```
<root>
   <list>
      <label>Label 1</label>
      <item>
         <p>some text</p>
      </item>
      <label>Label 2</label>
      <item>
         <p>some text</p>
         <p>some more text </p>
         <p>some more text</p>
      </item>
      <label>Label 3</label>
      <item>
         <p>other text</p>
         <p>some text</p>
         <p>some more text</p>
      </item>
   </list>
</root>
```

That is slightly different from your posted desired result, I am not sure whether that is an error in your posted sample or whether you want to treat a group with only one `item` differently, you could do that with an additional check inside of the `for-each-group`:

```
<xsl:template match="list">
<xsl:copy>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-adjacent="boolean(self::item)">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key()">
                <item>
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="current-group()[2]">
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>                             
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <xsl:apply-templates/>
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </item>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

as done in http://xsltransform.net/naZXpWX/1